# left join on a subquery or view loses rows with nulls

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join, mariadb

I used "left join" on a view & sub query but lost 'null' rows in mariadb 10.2.11+. I don't know how this happened. Can you explain it to me?

schema and data:

```
create table t1 (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(50),
  primary key (id)
) engine = innodb auto_increment = 1 default character set = utf8;
create table t2 (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  pid int not null,
  subname varchar(50),
  primary key (id)
) engine = innodb auto_increment = 1 default character set = utf8;
insert into t1(id, name) values (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');
insert into t2(pid, subname) values (1,'a_1'),(1,'a_2'),(1,'a_3'),
                                    (2,'b_1'),(2,'b_2'),(2,'b_3');
create table t2_1 as
    select * from t2 where id in ( select max(id) from t2 group by pid );
create view v2 as
    select * from t2 where id in ( select max(id) from t2 group by pid );
```

In the following queries, the left table is always `t1` and the right table is always equal to `select * from t2 where id in ( select max(id) from t2 group by pid )`.

left join with sub query:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t22.id as sid, t22.subname
from t1 left join (
    select * from t2 where id in ( select max(id) from t2 group by pid )
    ) as t22
on (t1.id = t22.pid);
```

result in mariadb 10.1.21 is ok:

```
+----+------+------+---------+
| id | name | sid  | subname |
+----+------+------+---------+
|  1 | a    |    3 | a_3     |
|  2 | b    |    6 | b_3     |
|  3 | c    | NULL | NULL    |
+----+------+------+---------+
```

result in mariadb 10.2.11 or 10.2.13 is wrong:

```
+----+------+------+---------+
| id | name | sid  | subname |
+----+------+------+---------+
|  1 | a    |    3 | a_3     |
|  2 | b    |    6 | b_3     |
+----+------+------+---------+
```

left join with table

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2_1.id as sid, t2_1.subname
from t1 left join t2_1
on (t1.id = t2_1.pid);
```

result in mariadb 10.1.21 is ok:

```
+----+------+------+---------+
| id | name | sid  | subname |
+----+------+------+---------+
|  1 | a    |    3 | a_3     |
|  2 | b    |    6 | b_3     |
|  3 | c    | NULL | NULL    |
+----+------+------+---------+
```

result in mariadb 10.2.11 or 10.2.13 is ok:

```
+----+------+------+---------+
| id | name | sid  | subname |
+----+------+------+---------+
|  1 | a    |    3 | a_3     |
|  2 | b    |    6 | b_3     |
|  3 | c    | NULL | NULL    |
+----+------+------+---------+
```

left join with view:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t22.id as sid, t22.subname
from t1 left join v2 as t22
on (t1.id = t22.pid);
```

result in mariadb 10.1.21 is ok:

```
+----+------+------+---------+
| id | name | sid  | subname |
+----+------+------+---------+
|  1 | a    |    3 | a_3     |
|  2 | b    |    6 | b_3     |
|  3 | c    | NULL | NULL    |
+----+------+------+---------+
```

result in mariadb 10.2.11 or 10.2.13 is wrong

```
+----+------+------+---------+
| id | name | sid  | subname |
+----+------+------+---------+
|  1 | a    |    3 | a_3     |
|  2 | b    |    6 | b_3     |
+----+------+------+---------+
```

Comment: result that run in version 10.3.5 is the same as version 10.2.13. I am so confuse that if I am wrong.

Comment: I check some different version mysql , the result is expacted. include mysql 5.5.5 - 8.0.3

Comment: Hi. Please **stop yelling**. Read the edit help. Please edit clarifications into your post, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Please read & act on [mcve]. PS This is unintelligible.

Comment: Thanks philipxy, I have imporved my question.

Comment: Please file a bug report with MariaDB.